# gorm many to one returns empty

Tags: go, go-gorm

I want to use `gorm` the use a many to one relationship in my project. 
My `struct`s are like this:

```
type Book struct {
    ID          uint
    Title       string
    Subtitle    string
    Chapters    []Chapter `gorm:"foreignkey:BookID;association_foreignkey:ID"`
```

}
    }

```
// TableName is book
func (Book) TableName() string {
    return "book"
}

// Chapter of books
type Chapter struct {
    ID      uint
    BookID  string
    Chapter string
}
```

What I want is to get chapters of a book by using this command:`book.chapters`.
I use the following codes to get books and chapters:

```
var book models.Book
    db.First(&book, "id = ?", 4)
    fmt.Println(book.ID, book.Chapters) // returns []
```

when I query chapters with book_id = 4, I get 11 results:

```
   var chapters []models.Chapter
   db.Find(&chapters, "book_id = ? ", 4)
   fmt.Println("len(chapters) = ", len(chapters)) // len(chapters) =11
```

and when I set db.LogMode(true) and see what happens in the code I see that querying `book` only queries the books not joining that with `chapters`:

`SELECT * FROM "book"  WHERE (id = 4) ORDER BY "book"."id" ASC LIMIT 1`

Is there something that I missed from the documentation? how should I make the book struct the get non-empty `book.chapters`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is probably in Preloading: http://gorm.io/docs/preload.html#Preload

Try the following:

```
var book models.Book
db.Preload("Chapters").First(&book, "id = ?", 4)
fmt.Println(book.ID, book.Chapters)
```

Comment: thanks, that exactly the solution, but do you know  is it possible to automate the process of preloading?

Comment: I tried `gorm:"PRELOAD:true"` tag but it doesn't work.

Comment: find the [soulotuin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50873996/auto-preloading-with-gorm-not-working-as-expected?rq=1) :  `db = db.Set("gorm:auto_preload", true)`, thanks for Preloading idea.