# using auto preload in golang orm - gorm

Tags: go, orm, grails-orm, go-gorm, go-gin

I am trying to use the `Preload` method on gorm database instance to auto preload implicitly by using the `gorm:"PRELOAD"` tag as i found in this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50873996/auto-preloading-with-gorm-not-working-as-expected).I find this not working
my model is as follows

```
// Exam model
type Exam struct {
    gorm.Model
    Course   Course    `gorm:"PRELOAD;references:ID"`
    VenueID  uint      `gorm:"column:venue_id"`  
    CourseID uint      `gorm:"column:course_id"` 
    Seat     string    `gorm:"column:seat"`
    Venue    Venue     `gorm:"PRELOAD;references:ID"`
    Duration string    `gorm:"column:duration"`
    Date     time.Time `gorm:"column:date"`
}
```

here is my controller

```
type ExamController struct {
    BaseController
}

func NewExamController(db *gorm.DB) *ExamController {
    return &ExamController{BaseController: BaseController{db: db, model: models.Exam{}}}
}

// GetAllExams retrieves all exams with preloaded associations
func (examController *ExamController) GetAllExams(context *gin.Context) {
    var exams []models.Exam

    // Fetch all exams from the database with preloaded associations
    if err := examController.db.Set("gorm:auto_preload", true).Find(&exams).Error; err != nil {
        context.AbortWithStatus(500)
        log.Println(err)
        return
    }

    // Return the exams as JSON response
    context.JSON(200, &exams)
}
```

the output is

```
{
    "ID": 2,
    "CreatedAt": "2023-07-02T12:50:58.929244104+03:00",
    "UpdatedAt": "2023-07-02T12:50:58.929244104+03:00",
    "DeletedAt": null,
    "Course": {
        "ID": 0,
        "CreatedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
        "UpdatedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
        "DeletedAt": null,
        "Name": "",
        "Code": "",
        "Facilitator": ""
    },
    "VenueID": 1,
    "CourseID": 2,
    "Seat": "A1",
    "Venue": {
        "ID": 0,
        "CreatedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
        "UpdatedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
        "DeletedAt": null,
        "Name": "",
        "Code": "",
        "Building": "",
        "Capacity": 0
    },
    "Duration": "2 hours",
    "Date": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
},
```

## **EXPECTED OUTPUT**

When i use Preload explicitly like below

```
    // Fetch all exams from the database with preloaded associations
    if err := examController.db.Preload("Course").Preload("Venue").Find(&exams).Error; err != nil {
        context.AbortWithStatus(500)
        log.Println(err)
        return
    }
```

I get  the following result which is the output i expected by using `auto preload`

```
{
    "ID": 2,
    "CreatedAt": "2023-07-02T12:50:58.929244104+03:00",
    "UpdatedAt": "2023-07-02T12:50:58.929244104+03:00",
    "DeletedAt": null,
    "Course": {
        "ID": 2,
        "CreatedAt": "2023-07-02T11:40:50.236979619+03:00",
        "UpdatedAt": "2023-07-02T11:40:50.236979619+03:00",
        "DeletedAt": null,
        "Name": "CLINICAL PHARMACOLOGY",
        "Code": "CPO 200",
        "Facilitator": "JOSEPH JACKSON"
    },
    "VenueID": 1,
    "CourseID": 2,
    "Seat": "A1",
    "Venue": {
        "ID": 1,
        "CreatedAt": "2023-07-02T12:43:39.256215902+03:00",
        "UpdatedAt": "2023-07-02T12:43:39.256215902+03:00",
        "DeletedAt": null,
        "Name": "LECTURE HALL 7",
        "Code": "L5",
        "Building": "LECTURE HALL",
        "Capacity": 400
    },
    "Duration": "2 hours",
    "Date": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
}
```